# Why is my mysql database table not allowing me to edit data manually?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

For some odd reason out of the blue my database in MySql will not allow me to manually edit any records. My guess is it never has. I am logged in with the Workbench under the root account. I have confirmed that the root matches any host as well as any schema.

I can edit other tables in the same database just fine. It is only 1 specific table that I am having trouble editing. Even if I write a query to run against the table it just says Executing forever and does nothing.

Any clues on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem. It was related to the fact that my table didn't have a Primary Key specified.